# Create OSX installer from Ruby program

Tags: osx, ruby

This was asked on SO, but closed as off topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21212634/151502

I'm looking for something that takes the ruby program that I've been given and wraps it up with everything (ruby-related) that it needs in order to run.

Ideally it would produce a .pkg that I could then wrap with some others into a .dmg for distribution. The end goal is to set up the ruby application to run as a service via launchctl.

I'm totally new to the world of ruby, so if I've left out important details let me know.

Comment: If someone with more rep wants to add an 'installer' tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for this might be [Traveling Ruby](http://phusion.github.io/traveling-ruby/) from phusion, as it's goals are to create stand-alone executable packages from ruby files

Comment: I'm well past that project now, and it looks like this didn't appear until later, but this looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, maybe more "approximately what I was looking for" but closer than the app bundle answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool that provides part of the solution: bundling the Ruby runtime and a Ruby script into a standalone Mac application, ruby2app:

https://github.com/codebykevin/ruby2app

It doesn't provide a package installer or DMG, but you can use other Mac tools to create those as part of a build workflow (cf. hdiutil and pkgbuild). Do you even need a package installer? The whole point of the self-contained app bundle is to install it by dragging it wherever you want. Package installers are only needed in situations where several different components must be installed in specific locations. They are not as relevant on the Mac as they are on Windows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I looked at your tool, but I needed to be able to set up a service that runs on startup, and as far as I can tell you can't do that by dragging an app bundle somewhere. It's also part of a larger set of things which do need to be installed in several specific places.